# How to write a stored procedure for my following code?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to use these two queries in a single query in prepared statement. 
I guess stored procedures will help me but I don't have any clear idea about stored procedures.

```
insert into call_dtl (consult_id,cust_id,ticket_id,created_ts)
    values (2,
        (select cd.cust_id from cust_dtl cd where cd.name='venkat'),
    '00001','2016-12-31 23:59:59');
update ticket_dtl t set t.stat_id="2" where t.ticket_id='00002';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
DELIMITER $$

USE `your_db_name`$$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `your_proc_name`$$

CREATE DEFINER=`your_user`@`your_host` PROCEDURE `your_proc_name`()
BEGIN
INSERT INTO call_dtl (consult_id,cust_id,ticket_id,created_ts) VALUES (2,(SELECT cd.cust_id FROM cust_dtl cd WHERE cd.name='venkat'),'00001','2016-12-31 23:59:59'); 
UPDATE ticket_dtl t SET t.stat_id="2" WHERE t.ticket_id='00002';
END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: thank you for ur reply ,i tried it sir but it gives an error like {you have an error in your SQL syntax:check the manual that corresponds to your mysql server version for the right syntax to use near '$$ DELIMETER'at line 5}